# Spring Data / JPA, Auditing, Envers ..history table missing columns from base table

Tags: hibernate, junit, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I am working through the various Spring Data features and evaluating for our application. I started with simple JPA persistence with JpaRepository and some simple JUnits tests (H2 Database) of the repository methods. Then I added some auditing of some tables having the create and update time and user with JUnit tests....so far so good.

Now I am trying to create a history table for some of the tables. So I went through the steps:

- added spring-data-envers to pom.xml
- added EnableJPARepositories to SpringBootApplication
  @SpringBootApplication
  @EnableCaching
  @EnableJpaAuditing(modifyOnCreate=false)
  @EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)

When I run my JUnits and look at the generated database I see that the audit columns (create user, create ts, update user, update ts are not present in the history table but they are in the base entity table.

So I ran some extra tests and my base entity extended an abstract class that contains the audit columns..so I could re-user for all entities that needed audit information. I changed my base entity to no longer extend the abstract audit class and added the audit attributes and methods. Now the history table does contain the audit columns.

So it appears that envers does not look at entity hierarchy to determine the columns to add to the history table.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I have used auditing support with base entity so it created all columns for audit table including base entity columns:

Need to annotate entity with `@Audited` :

```
    @Audited
    @Table(name="exam_answer",schema="exam")
    public class ExamAnswer extends CoreEnt{}
```

Base entity with fields:

```
@Audited
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CoreEnt {

    @Id
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    @Column(name = "oid")
    private  String oid;
    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private String createdDate;
    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private String updatedDate;
    @Column(name="state")
    private Byte state; ....
```

I used hibernate envers with spring data jpa.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Added properties for hibernate envers:(I set them over java config also can be set from application.properties)

```
protected Properties additionalProperties() {
    final Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", env.getProperty("hibernate.default_schema"));

    hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.default_schema", "audit");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix", "_aud");

    hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name", "rev");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.revision_type_field_name", "rev_type");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy", "org.hibernate.envers.strategy.DefaultAuditStrategy");

    hibernateProperties.setProperty("org.hibernate.envers.use_revision_entity_with_native_id", "false");

    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I annotate the parent class with @Audited, then the columns appear in the history table.

Comment: Envers will only create various `_AUD` history tables if it finds that an entity class is annotated with `@Audited` or if a declared property on an entity class is annotated with `@Audited`.